# How to copy a specific word from a .txt file to String/Integer in java?

Tags: java, file

I have a text file named `studentInfo.txt`.
The file contains these texts

```
376,Pronay sarker,CSE,hdofhdoif,64,3.19(Introduction to programming language one, Math calculus)
377,Plabon sarker,DS,iugfdofy98,64,3.2,(null)
388,Sourav Mojumdar,CSE,odfjdof33,64,3.29,(null)
379,Nobita,SWE,h3efe,65,4.5,(null)
```

These values are studentID, studentName, department, password, batch, cgpa and their courses. Please note that they're separated by `,` (comma).

I created a string `String name;`.But how do I assign the name of the student with student ID 379 (here it is Nobita)  into that string variable `name`?

I couldn't think of using `FileReader` since it reads files by a single character.  would you mind helping?

Comment: Note that this file is in a CSV format. Try searching on how to read that from CSV files.

Comment: `But how do I assign the name of the student with student ID 379 ` - By creating a Student class and applying the file data to instances of Student, [here is an example of how this could be done](https://controlc.com/cd8e0b50).